# помогите a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token

Tags: arduino

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>

#define SS_PIN 10
#define RST_PIN 9
#define Trig 7
#define Echo 6
#define ledPin 3
MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);

void setup() 
{  
  pinMode(Trig, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(Echo, INPUT); 
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT); 
; 


unsigned int impulseTime=0; 
unsigned int distance_sm=0; 
{
 Serial.begin(9600); 
 SPI.begin();  
 mfrc522.PCD_Init(); 
 Serial.println("Scan PICC to see UID and type...");
}

void loop()   
 {
  digitalWrite(Trig, HIGH); 
 delayMicroseconds(10); 
  digitalWrite(Trig, LOW); 
  impulseTime=pulseIn(Echo, HIGH); 
  distance_sm=impulseTime/58;  
  if (distance_sm<30) 
  {     
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
  }  
  else 
  {   
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW); 
  }  
  delay(100); 

  {
  byte uidCard[4] = {0x93, 0x48, 0x67, 0x9A}; 

 if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) {
  return;
 }

 // Select one of the cards
 if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) {
  return;
 }

        for (byte i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
          if (uidCard[i] != mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i])
            return;           
        }

  Serial.println("OPEN");
  // digitalWrite(); 
  delay(5000);
  // digitalWrite();      
}
```

Comment: у вас не равное кол-во открывающий и закрывающих скобок `{`, `}`

Comment: можешь переделать пожалуйста?

Comment: В строчке после `pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);` идет точка-запятая, а не скобка.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по форматированию, потеряна закрывающая операторная скобка

```
void setup() 
{  
  pinMode(Trig, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(Echo, INPUT); 
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT); 
; // <------------------------------- в этом месте


unsigned int impulseTime=0;
```

Но тогда непонятно, куда относится этот блок:

```
{
 Serial.begin(9600); 
 SPI.begin();  
 mfrc522.PCD_Init(); 
 Serial.println("Scan PICC to see UID and type...");
}
```

Судя по командам, он должен быть внутри функции `setup`

Но переменные `impulseTime` и `distance_sm` используются внутри функции `loop`, значит она должны быть объявлены или глобально или внутри `loop`, но никак не внутри `setup`.

После объявления функции `loop` количество открывающих и закрывающих операторных скобок тоже не совпадает.

Код похож на монстра Франкенштейна, собранного из разных кусков.

Проще переписать заново, чем пытаться исправлять.